# Asus k501u laptop boots abnormally

Tags: windows-10, boot, laptop, graphics-card, bios

The laptop turns on randomly with an unpredictable result.

The only thing that happens is predictable - it is clear that the screen turns on.

### After pressing the power button, the following scenarios are possible:

- The turn-on lamp flashes for a few seconds, the laptop turns off after a second or two.
- The fan turns on for 5-10 seconds, then the laptop turns off.
- An [hourglass](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BRKtM.jpg) appears on the screen.
- The hourglass appears, after 10-20 seconds the BIOS appears.

It's really looks like random generated events ((((((

### What did I do:

- Pull out the battery.
- Pulled ssd\hdd.
- Pull out the keyboard and touchpad.
- In the off state, pressed the power button for 45 seconds.
- Replaced thermal grease in the cooling system.
- Connect a second monitor via HDMI (no result)

### What i did before this:

Install nvidia drivers (windows 10) and set high-performance card by default. Then - reboot.

### What is also abnormal:

- In the BIOS there is a ["GOP version"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qf2aV.jpg) item with a value consisting of question marks.